# Ctrl + S в Selenium не работает (Как скачать страницу с css, js и проч.?)

Tags: python, selenium

Мне нужно скачать страницу сайта ([например](https://ege.sdamgia.ru/test?id=33103201&nt=True&pub=False&print=true)), перед этим я с помощью Selenium открываю ее. 
Использую Chrome Driver.
Стандартные ActionChains не работают (нажатие ctrl + s не детектится).

```
a = ActionChains(driver)
a.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').perform() #не работает
```

wget консольная утилита имеет проблемы с сопоставлением имен файлов, поэтому часть информации теряется.
Есть ли какие-то адекватные способы скачать веб-страницу со всеми js, css и прочими файлами, как это делает стандартное ctrl + s?

Comment: А так `driver.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + 's')`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: если через ActionChains(driver), вместо driver то ничего не произойдет, но ошибки не будет

Comment: А взять сорцы и поместить их в файл не подходит?

Comment: Перестают работать файлы svg, например

Comment: @CodeIsmylife, угу, я сглупил, нужно вызывать `send_keys` у элементов, например: `body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')` + `body.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + 's')`

Comment: Все еще не работает